# SQL SERVER-Usar una suma de un campo en otro campo para sumar

Tags: sql-server, databricks

tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
    ((ms.ActualQuantityDeliveredinSalesUnits / od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency)-inv.NetValueOfTheBillingItemInDocumentCurrency AS ENRUTADO
    ,((od.CumulativeConfirmedQuantityInSalesUnit/od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency) - ENRUTADO AS CONFIRMA
    ,(od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits - od.CumulativeConfirmedQuantityInSalesUnit) * od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency - CREDITO - HORIZONTE AS NO_CONFIRMA
    ,IF(od.OverallStatusOfCreditChecks = 'B' ,od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency,0) AS CREDITO
    ,IF(od.OverallStatusOfCreditChecks = 'B' ,0,((IF(od.DeliveryBlock = 'ZD',1,0)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency) - CREDITO)) AS HORIZONTE
FROM tb_csc_otr_orderdata` od
```

Como ven, en la primer linea calculo el *ENRUTADO* y ese calculo lo resto para el *CONFIRMA* y mas adelante utilizo otros valores calculados.
No se me ocurre como usar esos valores calculados dentro de la misma consulta, ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: IF no es una función válida en Sql Server. Quizá intentas usar [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se pueden usar campos que resuelve la select y que les das un alias en la misma fila.

**Opción 1**

```
SELECT 
    ((ms.ActualQuantityDeliveredinSalesUnits / od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency)-inv.NetValueOfTheBillingItemInDocumentCurrency AS ENRUTADO
    ,((od.CumulativeConfirmedQuantityInSalesUnit/od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency) - 
--      ENRUTADO 
-- Ese enrutado lo tienes que sustituir por su correspondiente fórmula completa.
 (((ms.ActualQuantityDeliveredinSalesUnits / od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency)-inv.NetValueOfTheBillingItemInDocumentCurrency)
        AS CONFIRMA
    ,(od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits - od.CumulativeConfirmedQuantityInSalesUnit) * od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency - CREDITO - HORIZONTE AS NO_CONFIRMA
    ,IF(od.OverallStatusOfCreditChecks = 'B' ,od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency,0) AS CREDITO
    ,IF(od.OverallStatusOfCreditChecks = 'B' ,0,((IF(od.DeliveryBlock = 'ZD',1,0)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency) - CREDITO)) AS HORIZONTE
FROM tb_csc_otr_orderdata` od
```

Directamente donde pone Enrutado y así con el resto, expones lo que corresponde con eso.

**Opción 2**

Utilizar una tabla derivada o cte te permite tratar las columnas ya calculadas en la salida.

```
   SELECT D.ENRUTADO, D.PREVIOENRUTADO-ENRUTADO AS CONFIRMA, * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ((ms.ActualQuantityDeliveredinSalesUnits / od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency)-inv.NetValueOfTheBillingItemInDocumentCurrency AS ENRUTADO
        ,((od.CumulativeConfirmedQuantityInSalesUnit/od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency)  AS PREVIOENRUTADO
        ,(od.CumulativeOrderQuantityInSalesUnits - od.CumulativeConfirmedQuantityInSalesUnit) * od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency  AS PREVIO_NO_CONFIRMA
        ,IF(od.OverallStatusOfCreditChecks = 'B' ,od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency,0) AS CREDITO
        ,IF(od.OverallStatusOfCreditChecks = 'B' ,0,((IF(od.DeliveryBlock = 'ZD',1,0)*od.NetValueOfTheOrderItemInDocumentCurrency) - CREDITO)) AS HORIZONTE
    FROM tb_csc_otr_orderdata` od
    ) AS D
```

Tendrás que reformular la última columna para poder calcularla en la salida.

No te puedo acercar más al resultado, porque no has expuesto una pregunta con un escenario completo que se pueda reproducir, además de que la sintaxis que has pegado parece contener errores.

Comment: Al final lo solucioné haciendo subconsultas como lo mencionas. Gracias!